# dataGridView Controlled context menu click

Tags: c#

I want to make it so that if the first row is right clicked and an option on the context menu is clicked it will do a specific function, and if the second row is right clicked it will do a specific function etc. So I've tried several different codes and none work but this is just my simplified version of the code, so how can I make it do as I want?

```
    private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
        if (row.Selected.Equals(0) == true && e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && contextMenuStrip1.Text == "Test")
        {
            MessageBoxEx.Show("Test ok");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your purpose is perform different task for different gridview row with same menu item click event.

1- On mouse down, just save the DataGridView rowIndex.

2- On menu item click event, use the saved rowindex to decide your different task.

3- Since Mouse click will fire after context menu hence use MouseDown Instead mouse click event.

```
int RowIndex = 0;
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow == null)
        return;           

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        RowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index ;               
    }
}

private void testToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //MenuStrip item click event
{
    if (RowIndex == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (RowIndex == 1)
    {

    }
}
```